# Need to reset android AOSP code to Lollipop

Tags: android, android-source, repo

I have downloaded the current master of Android AOSP which is Android 6.0 source code.

Is there a way available using repo to set the master to Android 5.1 so that all git repositories are set accordingly?

Note: I wish to do this without downloading again.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, and a logical course of action but it has been explicitly recommended not to do this - allegedly things are not consistent enough between repositories for this to work reliably across releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html):

> To check out a branch other than "master", specify it with -b. For a
>   list of branches, see [Source Code Tags and Builds](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html#source-code-tags-and-builds).
>
> ```
> $ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
> ```

**Edit**

> Note: I wish to do this without downloading again.

You can try with:

```
repo init -b <manifest-branch>
repo sync -j8
```

**Edit 2**

> I want to know if there is way to do it without downloading. The sync
>   would download from google servers.

The [documentation](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html#sync) is really clear about the `sync` command:

> Downloads new changes and updates the working files in your local
>   environment. If you run repo sync without any arguments, it will
>   synchronize the files for all the projects.
>
> When you run repo sync, this is what happens:
>
> - If the project has never been synchronized, then repo sync is equivalent to git clone. All branches in the remote repository are
>     copied to the local project directory.
> - If the project has already been synchronized once, then repo sync is equivalent to:
>
>   ```
>   git remote update 
>   git rebase origin/<BRANCH>
>   ```
>
>   where  is the currently checked-out branch in the local
>     project directory. If the local branch is not tracking a branch in the
>     remote repository, then no synchronization will occur for the project.
> - If the git rebase operation results in merge conflicts, you will need to use the normal Git commands (for example, git rebase
>     --continue) to resolve the conflicts.

Since you already synchronized the project once the `sync` command is equivalent to a `rebase`.

Comment: Do I download the whole branch again using repo sync then? Is there a way without downloading?

Comment: I want to know if there is way to do it without downloading. The sync would download from google servers.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a clarification about the `sync` command. Let me know if it works for you.